# What movie features a hovering spherical robot that kills a man with a propeller blade?

Tags: story-identification, movie

One of the most memorable scenes is where one of the characters is killed by a hovering spherical robot about 1-2 ft in diameter (looks a little bit like the pokémon fortress). The robot sticks out a little propeller blade about 4 inches wide and saws through the guy’s clipboard (which for some reason he chooses to protect himself with) and into his abdomen. The guy who is in charge of the robot says something like "Why did you do that? He was a good man" to the robot, which I think must've had a mind of its own as it didn't seem to care.

Another thing I remember in the film is these people sitting at control panels and they wear long dark brown robes, and wear large reflective helmets so you can't see their faces.

I'm sorry there isn't a lot of detail here, but I remember seeing this movie when I was really young and it terrified me. I'd love to know what it is, so any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Were these the robots in question; http://www.plasticpals.com/http://www.plasticpals.com/wp-content/uploads//2010/04/BlackHole-robot-props.jpg

Comment: Or these; http://www.horrorsniped.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/-397852508551162560.jpg?

Comment: Your first link is listed as 403 Forbidden. The second link works, and I'd love to own one of those Phantasm spheres.

Comment: Try this link instead; http://s840.photobucket.com/user/LukeCariaga/media/San-Diego-Comic-Con-Original-Disney-Black-Hole-Props-01-x1200.jpg.html

Comment: There is a whole movie series about flying balls that kill people... the *Phantasm* movies.  (Theoretically they were about other things but IMHO the flying balls were the part that people really liked.  Look at the posters... after the first movie, each poster is mainly about the flying ball.  The tag-line of the second movie was "THE BALL IS BACK!")  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079714/movieconnections?ref_=tt_ql_trv_6

Comment: The flying orbs where the good robots. You are thinking of the Disney's The Black Hole. The evil robot, Maximilian, uses a spinning blade to kill a main character. The MC is holding a clipboard at the time, and tries to protect himself with it.

Comment: If memory serves, the spheres from the Phantasm movies used a corkscrew, not a propeller- but then I only saw the previews, not the movies themselves.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think it is Disney's [The Black Hole](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078869/) from 1979. For being a Disney feature, it was more adult and dark, trying to compete with films like Star Wars and Close Encounters.

Here is an image of the crew:
[image]

It also **did** feature a person being killed in the manner you described, although it was done by the large red robot Maximilian. (There *were* spherical robots, but they were good guys.)

[image]

Comment: Max killed someone with a spinning blade; http://theageofvolcanoes.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/black-hole-max_481x205.jpg

Comment: Perfect match for the description; hard to believe any other movie would copy such a brainless execution.

Comment: As a kid in 1979 it was certainly creepy and scary. I saw it again a couple years ago, and, well, not so much anymore.

Comment: Yes that's it! Thanks for helping. I was 5/6 when i watched it and that scene gave me terrible nightmares. I watched it again today and it wasn't so bad haha. Thanks again.

Comment: My apologies for any perceived overreach on my part. I thought it worth mentioning that there are spherical robots, but that they're not involved in the killing.

Comment: I just didn't like the bots names being so distracting. The punctuation and numbers just seemed to clutter up the look. Sorry. (I saw the movie when it came out, because I'm old, even bought the story LP, and I didn't remember the numbers, or what BOB stood for. I remember Vital Information Necessary CENTralized...) Meet ya halfway?